# I want to make staging database the same as production on Azure

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service, sql-server-2014

My production and staging databases are on Azure and I want to make staging the same as production. I have no idea what to do, I have never worked with databases. I use SQL Server 2014.

Comment: Are you attempting to use the **same** database for prod and stage OR are you talking about making these databases contain the same data OR are you talking about some other scenario? 
What have you tried?

Comment: my production database name  **production_vanilla** and staging database name is **staging_vanilla** both are at azure now staging database contain less data and i want to make **staging_vanilla** data same as  **production_vanilla**  mean i want to copy **production_vanilla** data and paste in **staging_vanilla**  @drediske

Answer (score 5):

There are a few ways to do this, but the quickest way would probably be to replace your staging database when you want the updated data by [Creating a new database as a copy](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-copy-portal/). Now, this would wipe out any changes to your staging database, but would be the fastest way.

More complicated, but probably a bit more about what you're actually thinking of, would be setting up [azure data sync](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/the_cloud_pilot/2011/10/24/your-first-sql-azure-data-sync-step-by-step/) from Prod -> Staging.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer - The other answers here are missing the OP's point entirely.

Answer (score 1):

Staging Azure web app has different configuration with production Azure web app. We can configure the same connection string at Azure portal to achieve this requirement. Refer to [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure/#enabling-diagnostic-logs) for more information about how to configure connection string in Azure portal.  At runtime, Azure Web App will automatically retrieves values in Azure portal and makes them available to code running in your website. If the same connection string configured in Azure portal, the staging and production will use the same database.

Comment: no i don't want to use same database actually my production db is latest and staging db is old and i face issue when i made some change and test it on staging because all data is not available on staging db u understand what i mean?

Comment: As I know, Azure web app does not support copy data when swap the web site. I would recommend you to copy the data after swapping, then configure the new connection string in Azure portal. Refer to this article for more information about copy Azure SQL database: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-copy-portal/.

Comment: Thanks for help but i already read this article it shows only how to copy a database after copy how i replace data to staging? @Jambor-MSFT

Comment: I am afraid we need to configure the new connection string in Azure staging web app Application settings page after the database has copied.